# How to get Result from a Promise object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, redux

Working with function which returns Promise object like on the screenshot. How I can get PromiseResult from this object?

[image: Promise object]

Comment: result.then((data) => ... // data is your result array)

Comment: someFunction(...yourArguments).then(result=>doSomethingWith(result))

Comment: `const result = await mypromise`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result of a promise by using .then() like so:

```js
functionThatReturnsPromise().then((result) => {
  //do something with result
})
.catch(console.error)
```

Another option is to use `async` and `await` like so:

```js
async function main() {
  const result = await functionThatReturnsPromise()
  // do something with result
}

main().then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

If your environment or compiler supports [top-level await](https://2ality.com/2019/12/top-level-await.html) you can skip the `main` wrapper function like so:

```js
try {
  const result = await functionThatReturnsPromise()
  // do something with result
}
catch (err) {
  console.error(err)
}
```

Always remember to `catch` or `.catch` otherwise you will encounter [Unhandled Promise Rejection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40500490/what-is-an-unhandled-promise-rejection).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .then() function
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

```
yourFunction().then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more conversant with Python but have to deal with JS and it makes me crazy.
I spent a ton of time searching for an answer to this question, and it's been asked a bunch before, with a lot of varying answers, some rather convoluted, almost all of which show how to manipulate the result inside the async context, e.g. console.log(), but not how to pull the data into a global variable.

[JS How to extract data from a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62544990/js-how-to-extract-data-from-a-promise)

[How to extract data from a resolved promise javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120414/how-to-extract-data-from-a-resolved-promise-javascript)

https://dev.to/ramonak/javascript-how-to-access-the-return-value-of-a-promise-object-1bck

In the last one, several commenters queried the OP on this, saying that's not really the answer they wanted. The OP replied to one with a code snippet, and the commenter replied back - didn't work!

Using the toy object provided by the OP, this works for me and is very simple, just how I like it:

```
var request = async () => {
    var user = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    .then((response) => response.json());
    return user;
};
var userData = await request('PromiseResult');
var address = userData.address;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you run this code in your browser yo get the same structure:

```
function createPromise(){
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        resolve([{value:{},label:'Malmo'}])
    })
}

const rta = createPromise()
rta
```

to get its data you can do:

```
rta.then(array => console.log(array[0].label))
```